# Selenium 2 Webdriver - Div tag moves up when I try to do sendKeys

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I started learning selenium 2 since few days and when I try to automate the test, I am getting the below error. 
Issue: I have a page made up of 3 div tags - first one is a header that is horizontal and then I have 2 div tags that sit next to each other div2 is left hand side and div3 is right hand side. 
When I try to do enter data using selenium like element.sendKeys("test") it moves the whole Div tag up and disturbs the page layout. The only option I found was to use the Javascript executor and use jquery to enter data, but i can't do this for all the elements as the website has the same layout everywhere.

Can you please help me with this issue?

I am able to pull the div down by changing the padding-top to a higher value.

This works fine when we automate and replay , the div tag does not get disturbed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try entering text to the div by:

```
element.Text = "Your text";
```

I'm not sure why your div is being moved, but I imagine this might be a web layout issue rather than a selenium one. Have you tried adding a textbox or something into the div to display the text?

Answer (score 0):

I have just had a similar problem which was caused by using javascript to change the 'style' of the 'div'.

Because the original style of the div included its location on the page, overwriting it caused it to move.

The way I solved this was when changing the style, I ADDED to the style, rather than replacing it completely.

Hope this helps.